# ffmpegの実行結果について(保存場所などについて)

Tags: ffmpeg

ffmpegを使い動画をエンコードした後の保存場所がわからないです。
ffmpegを使ったあとエラーも出ずにエンコードは終了したのですが、肝心のエンコード後のファイルが見当たりません。
実行じたコマンドは

```
ffmpeg -i test.mp4 -threads 2 -codec:v libx264 -s:v 1280x720 -aspect:v 16:9 -b:v 256k -map 0 -f segment -segment_format mpegts -segment_time 10 -segment_list stream.m3u8 streamfiles/stream%03d.ts
```

これなんですが、保存場所は`streamfiles`というディレクトリですよね？
実行した場所は`/usr/share/nginx/www/streamfiles`でこのディレクトリ内に`test.mp4`が入っています。

またffmpegの実行結果は

```
ffmpeg version N-75926-gce0834b Copyright (c) 2000-2015 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.6 (Debian 4.6.3-14+rpi1)
  configuration: --arch=armel --target-os=linux --enable-shared --enable-gpl --enable-libx264 --enable-nonfree
  libavutil      55.  3.100 / 55.  3.100
  libavcodec     57.  5.100 / 57.  5.100
  libavformat    57.  3.100 / 57.  3.100
  libavdevice    57.  0.100 / 57.  0.100
  libavfilter     6. 11.100 /  6. 11.100
  libswscale      4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
  libswresample   2.  0.100 /  2.  0.100
  libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'test.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf56.40.100
  Duration: 00:00:03.28, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 10159 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1920x1080, 10156 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 1200k tbn, 2400k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
Illegal instruction
```

となりました。
これはエンコードできていますよね？
もし成功しているのであればエンコードで出来たファイルはどこに保存されているのでしょう、、、
分かるかた教えて欲しいです。

これがエラーで失敗していることはわかりました！
過去にクロスコンパイルのことも聞いていますが、今回は直接raspiで実行しています。

Comment: 最後に `illegal intruction` とあるってことは失敗してるんぢゃないっすかね？失敗してりゃ出力ファイルは無くて当然です。

Comment: これって失敗だったんですね、、、
ありがとうございます！

Answer (score 2):

`Illegal instruction` というのは、CPUが理解できない命令を実行しようとしたときに表示される**エラーです**。ffmpeg が検知して ffmpeg が表示するエラーメッセージは赤文字などわかりやすく表示されますが、これはより低レベルで起きているものなので、飾り気のないメッセージが突然現れて落ちます。

ので具体的には、

- ffmpeg（や関連ライブラリ） のバグを踏んだ
- `./configure` のオプションを間違えている
  （特定のCPUにしかない命令で最適化をかけたりもするので）
- クロスコンパイルで、ターゲット環境を指定せずに `./configure` した
  （オプションを指定しないと `./configure` する環境に合わせて最適化設定を行ってしまう）

のいずれかではないでしょうか。

---

過去の質問を拝見すると色々試行錯誤されているようですが、最終的にどのようにしてlibx264やffmpegをビルドしたのかがわからないので、具体的にどの手順が間違っているかはわかりません。

ただ、libx264の `./configure` で `--extra-cflags='-march=armv6' --extra-ldflags='-march=armv6'` をつけないと未サポートの命令を使ってしまう（おそらく `Illegal instrution`）という話を見かけたので、ひょっとしたらこれで解決するかもしれません。

https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/RaspberryPi?confirm_email=&email_confirm=&action=diff&version=7&old_version=6

Comment: クロスコンパイルの方法試そうとしたのですが、結局上手くできずに直接ビルドしました。
まずはlibx264のconfigureのオプションを確認して試してみます！
ありがとございます。

Answer (score 0):

教えて頂いた--extra-cflags='-march=armv6' --extra-ldflags='-march=armv6'というオプションを./configureにつけてmakeしたら
common/arm/quant-a.S: Assembler messages:
common/arm/quant-a.S:362: Error: selected processor does not support ARM mode `rbit r1,r1'

common/arm/quant-a.S:363: Error: selected processor does not support ARM mode`rbit r1,r1'
Makefile:217: recipe for target 'common/arm/quant-a.o' failed
make: *** [common/arm/quant-a.o] Error 1
というエラーがでました。
ARMモードをサポートしていないっていうのはわかるのですが、これはarmv6をarmv7にしてなおりますか？
これはどう対処すればいいでしょうか。

Answer (score 0):

新しい質問ですよね。新規発言にして欲しいところですがとりあえず・・・

`raspberry-pi` なんでしょうか `raspberry-pi 2 model B` なんでしょうか？
要するに CPU は `BCM2835` なのか `BCM2836` なのか、どっちでしょう？

`raspberry-pi 2 model B` は `BCM2836` つまり `armv7`
`raspberry-pi` は `BCM2835` つまり `armv6`
`rbit` は `armv6` では使用できない `armv7` なら OK

ウチの `raspberry-pi 2 model B` の [raspbian](/questions/tagged/raspbian) では

```
$ ./config.guess
armv7l-unknown-linux-gnueabihf
```

となりました。
たぶん `raspberry-pi 2 model B` なら `--extra-cflags` なしでも動作するんでしょう。

同様

```
$ ./configure --extra-cflags='-march=armv7'
No working C compiler found
```

なのでむやみに指定しても無駄っぽいです。

Comment: 私が使っているのはRaspberry Pi B+です。ということはarmv6なんでしょうか？この質問は新規発言してみます。ありがとうございました！

Comment: `rpi B+` だと `BCM2835` なので `armv6` っすね。